# CSS won't work unless I use external site

Tags: css, bxslider

On my Site.master file, I have the following in my `<head>`:

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- easing Javascript file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bxslider.com/lib/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ( $ ) {
        $('.slider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'horizontal',
            infiniteLoop: true,
            auto: true,
            autoStart: true,
            autoDirection: 'next',
            autoHover: true,
            pause: 3000,
            autoControls: false,
            pager: true,
            pagerType: 'full',
            controls: true,
            captions: true,
            speed: 500
        });
    });
</script>
```

What happens is, the little bullets that represent each slide as well as the "prev" and "next" arrows are not using the images they are supposed to. If I change the CSS reference to "http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" instead of my own copy, it works FINE.  I have all the images and folders in the correctly reference locations.

The issue here is, I want to change some of the CSS, but I can't if I use the external file.

Comment: Are your images in correct folder? Or is your css pointing correct path for images?

Comment: This is likely being caused because the paths to the image files are incorrect in your local copy. In firebug or similar when you inspect element does it show you the path to the image? When you mouse over the path does it say it couldn't load the image? If so, check your CSS file and make sure the image paths point to where the local images are stored.

Comment: Yes... "/images/controls.png" as well as "lib/images/controls.png" just for giggles.

Comment: I wonder if the image work because you're using the images relative to the scripts path i.e. *their* images on *their* domain?

Comment: Well, it's not linking any of the CSS I don't think.  When it works, it puts everything in a white box with a drop shadow... which I want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it needs to be pointed like this:

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src=".//Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- easing Javascript file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src=".//plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src=".//js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href=".//lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day) Had the same issue and fixed by adding ".//" before jquery.bxslider.css path